# What does the Haskell list syntax without commas mean?

Tags: list, haskell, syntax

I'm looking through some Haskell code and I saw an expression with the following shape:

```
[A B C D]
```

I know that a list in Haskell would have commas between the elements. What does this notation mean? Could someone point me to the appropriate documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4 elements separated by only space means the same thing inside list brackets as it does outside them: `A` is applied to `B` and then to `C` and then to `D`.

Comment: Ah, yes. The result would just be a single-element list with the result of the application. Looks obvious in hindsight. Coming from a Scheme background, the lack of explicit parenthesiaation (like `[(A B C D)]`) confused me.

Comment: @AtharvaShukla Aha, I guess that's the Scheme-background version of the common confusion people from C-call-syntax-background have, where they expect to need to write `f(x)` instead of `f x`.